# I can not deploy (publish) Blazor web in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor

Please see the screenshots and message:

[image]

[image]

Error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> (Inner Exception #0)
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

Comment: You seem to be targeting preview 5. Change your libraries to a release version. I think you need to make it self contained if your using a preview that is not supported natively on the platform

Answer (score 0):

As .Net [SDK7.0.100](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) is the latest released version and in preview, so it's not incompatible with VS.
It is suggested to use the other versions of .Net SDK like below mentioned which are compatible in order to resolve this kind of errors and publish the blazor web app to Azure App Service:

Try to add the below code in the  `global.json` file:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can follow the below steps:

Goto VS->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager console as shown in below Screenshot:

[image]

Output:
[image]